# Relationship fields error?

Tags: compile-error

In my trigger i get the error like this at compile time

```
    List<ID> cIds = new List<ID>();

        for(Case cObj : Trigger.new){

              if(cObj.Account.Name != null && cObj.IntegrationTo__c != null){

                cIds.add(cObj.Id); 

             } 
        }

 List<Integration__c> ll  =  [SELECT id,name,username__c,password__c,URL__c,account__c,integrationwith__c FROM Integration__c WHERE Case__c IN:cIds AND Case__r.AccountName = account__c AND Case__r.IntegrationTo__c = integrationwith__c ];
```

Error : Error: Compile Error: expecting a colon, found 'account__c' at line 14 column 181

Thanks

Comment: don't post same code again and again. we saw you got error in your previous post. wait will post some answer there itself.

Comment: You cannot use field API name for filters, try collecting the lookup values which you want to match in a set and use it in where clause.

Comment: @Rahul thanks for replyling ok collecting the Ids in Set is fine but help me to in SOQL query

Comment: can once check the answers for this question http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/166904/unexpected-token-unexpected-syntax-missing-rparen-at/166917#166917   is it related?

Answer (score -1):

Salesforce doesn't identify "account__c". you need to modify your code : -

```
List<ID> cIds = new List<ID>();
**List<String> lst_accountName = new List<String>();
List<ID> lst_integrationIds = new List<ID>();**
for(Case cObj : Trigger.new){
      if(cObj.Account.Name != null && cObj.IntegrationTo__c != null){
        cIds.add(cObj.Id);  
        **lst_accountName.add(cObj.Account.Name);** 
        **lst_integrationIds.add(cObj.IntegrationTo__c);** 
     } 
}

List ll = [SELECT id,name,username__c,password__c,URL__c,account__c,integrationwith__c FROM Integration__c WHERE Case__c IN:cIds AND Case__r.AccountName IN :  lst_accountName AND Case__r.IntegrationTo__c In :  lst_integrationIds];
```

This should work